# How do I install linux-firmware from the git repoistory for Ryzen 3 2200g w/ VEGA iGPU?

Tags: amd-graphics, git, amdgpu

I've cloned the archive at https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+git/linux-firmware/+ref/artful, but I don't know where to go from there. Or should I get it from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu?

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repository, open a terminal in the directory of the repo and run the following command

```
sudo cp amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu/
```